# Change section name into subsection names in header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to insert a header in the `book` class such that:

- Odd pages show only the book title on the left header:
- Even pages show either the section name, or the subsection (if this exists) on the right header

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{Book title}\fancyfoot[CO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}\fancyfoot[CE]{\thepage} %this should be defined in some other way
\pagestyle{fancy}

\author{Author}
\title{Test book}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Test chapter]{Test chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[4-11]

\markedsection{Short section title}{Long section title}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

However, even pages do not show the section name, while they show the subsection name when that is already "initialized".
How can I define a command that changes the section name into the subsection name of the header?

Comment: @Bobyandbob, not exactly. In the linked case, every even page has the subsection name as header. In my case, the header has to be the section name, except when the subsection is initialized, in which case I want the header to be the subsection name.

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: Where is `\markedsection` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `book` class there is no real `\subsectionmark` command -- it uses the `\let\subsectionmark\@gobble` statement from `latex.ltx`.

Within all section levels commands defined with `\@startsection` and finally using `\@sect`, there is the call `\csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}`, which will set the mark if `#1mark`, i.e. if `\subsectionmark` would be really usefully defined, but it is used as `\@gobble`, i.e. throwing away the argument for `book.cls`.

So one possible solution is to define `\subsectionmark`, I used the definition of `\sectionmark` within `\ps@headings` style from `book.cls` and changed it slightly.

Since all `\....mark` commands use `\markboth` which is setting internal variables, the last call to `\markboth` will set the real `\@leftmark` and `\@rightmark` settings, so the last call of a mark on the page is the winner!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\subsectionmark#1{%
  \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
      \thesubsection. \ %
      \fi
      #1}}}
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{Book title}\fancyfoot[CO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}\fancyfoot[CE]{\thepage} %this should be defined in some other way
\pagestyle{plain}

\author{Author}
\title{Test book}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter[Test chapter]{Test chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[4-11]

\subsection{Foo subsection}
%\markedsection{Short section title}{Long section title}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I was able to grab the logic even if I am not an expert! However, I still have the same problem as before: even pages do NOT show the section name on the header (that is, an empty header), while they show the subsection name (when this is declared).

Comment: @Py-ser: I checked and the page `6`  has the section title as you requested, here on the right side of the page, since you specified `RE`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I vote always Christian. Look look :-). The votes are gratis.

Comment: @Sebastiano: As are mine...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, you are right. However, it seems that if I `\input{chapterfile.tex}` the section name is not shown. Is it because, in that way, I do not explicitely initialize the section? does this make sense?

Comment: @Py-ser: Well, it would be nice to  know what is inside that `chapterfile.tex`

Comment: In the `chapterfile.tex` there is just text, plus a call for the `\subsection`. I checked: if I introduce a `\section{}` in the `chapterfile.tex` I get what I want. One last thing: how can I put the `\chapter{name}` (instead of the ``section{name}) in the `[RE]` header?

Comment: @Py-ser: I'll take a look

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, or you can address me to some useful link?