# Why is rightmark not appearing in header?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am a complete newbie with LaTeX and I couldn't find a solution to the following problem: I want the section to appear on the left hand side of the header, the subsection in the middle and the page to the left. I wanted to use the following:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=1.5cm,headsep=1cm{geometry}  
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyhf{}  
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}  
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}  
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}  
\fancyheadoffset[R,L]{1cm}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
```

It works perfectly for the section and the page but the subsection doesn't appear at all. I managed to redefine `\rightmark` via `\renewcommand{\rightmark}{\thesubsection}` so that at least the number of the subsection appears but how do I get the title of the subsection as well into the center of the header?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. By default, `\subsection` does not set the marks for the `book` class, but it is unclear which document class your using. Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments. Here's a possible workaround: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356565/change-section-name-into-subsection-names-in-header

Answer (score 4):

The macro `\rightmark` is automatically update by LaTeX when it processes a `\markright` instruction, so you mustn't redefine it yourself.

By default, with the `article` class, `\section` issues `\markboth`, which sets `\leftmark` (and `\rightmark`, but usually sets this to empty) via the macro `\sectionmark` that's automatically called by `\section`.

You have to redefine `\subsectionmark` that, by default, does nothing to issue `\markright`:

```
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left=2.5cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  top=3.0cm,
  bottom=1.5cm,
  headsep=1cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyheadoffset[R,L]{1cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

As Gustavo Mezzetti remarks, the macro `\subsectionmark` *does* execute `\markright`, provided `twoside` is in force *and* the page style is set to `headings` or `myheadings`. However, this is not relevant for the task at hand, since the pagestyle is declared to be `fancy`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I added the information, but it's not really relevant, as the OP is doing `\pagestyle{fancy}`. As a linguistic remark, *mustn't* is strong enough to not require more emphasis.

Comment: I tried this approach. I replaced "\blinddocument" with some sections and subsections. I could not suceed in getting subsections to appear in hearder .